# Call Word Menu-Button in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word, office-addins, word-addins, ribbonx

everyone,

I am new to VBA and would like to know if it is possible to execute a menu button from a WordAddIn.

In the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFy7W.png) you can see which button I would like to execute using VBA.

Unfortunately, I can't record it via macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Word object model allows executing built-in ribbon controls using the [CommandBars.ExecuteMso](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbars.executemso) method which executes the control identified by the `idMso` parameter. This method is useful in cases where there is no object model for a particular command. Works on controls that are built-in `buttons`, `toggleButtons`, and `splitButtons`.

But in your case the control comes from a third-party add-in which doesn't expose IDs and the `CommandBars.ExecuteMso` method can't find it and invoke the command programmatically.

To get the job done you may consider using the [Microsoft Active Accessibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/microsoft-active-accessibility) which is a Component Object Model (COM)-based technology that improves the way accessibility aids work with applications running on Microsoft Windows. It provides dynamic-link libraries that are incorporated into the operating system as well as a COM interface and API elements that provide reliable methods for exposing information about UI elements.

Also you may contact the add-in vendor for providing public methods that can be called from your solution. That's also a possible workaround instead of calling UI elements on the ribbon.